# How to embed java application into a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a simple java application and want to embed it into a jsp page. At the minute it takes a parameter at the command line, is it possible to pass the parameter from the web page, if so how?

Thanks

~ Kyle G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to make this an applet (I'm guessing you do).

If so, [Sun's applet tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html) has a section on converting applications to applets.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the link to your little app:

> www.yourpage.com/index.jsp?item=myitem

and in your index.jsp you can get it in this way:

```
...
This is the item passed by GET:
<%= request.getParameter("item") 
//your code here
%>
...
```